# What other file should be corrected after removing an error in Element.xml?

Tags: custom-list, column, visual-studio-2013, elements-xml, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows Server 2012.
I modified a Field in the Element.xml of my list columns because I made a typo when I typed it.
Nevermind I corrected the typo. When I trying to access the list that using this column on sharepoint I get an error that talking about the typo that I've already revised.

I did disabled the feature that contain the colulms.
I have updated the solution and deployed it.
I did enabled the feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any feature deactivation code to delete the list, it is going to remain and still contain your typo. If you don't have any feature activation code to check if the list exists and fix it, the typo will remain.

If you've updated your feature, deactivate it and delete your list. Then activate the feature to provision the list again, and the typo should be gone.